# Netlogo Creating a Link with a turtle when they both hit the same patch

Tags: netlogo

Maybe i worded the question wrong but what i want to do in the code is when another turtle meets another turtle they create links with each other
I know its

```
to go
tick
make-circle
move
if ticks >= timer1 [stop]
end

to move
ask turtles
[
create-links-with other turtles ;here is where i want to put the code
set heading random 360 fd 1]
create-network
end

to create-network
  ask links [
  set thickness 0.01 * counter
if [patch-here] of end1 = [patch-here] of end2
[set counter (counter + 1)]

]
end
```

but im not sure how to word it correctly to link when they meet how do i do that

Comment: What do you mean by meet? The position is continuous, so they will never be in the exact same place. Do you mean 'on the same patch' or 'within some distance' or something else?

Comment: When two turtles meet each other in the same patch or within a certain distance, Also when they meet each other they start counting with the links how many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish a breed variable for your counts. Then create a link between all turtles that are on the same patch with other turtles-here. Then increment that count variable for when the others turtles have met the original calling turtle. I'll note that I increment the count variable by .5 because each turtle in the link will increment it (there's 2 turtles, so .5 * 2 = 1).

```
links-own [meets]

to setup
  clear-all
  crt 100 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [fd 1]
  ask turtles [rt random 90]

  ask turtles [ create-links-with other turtles-here]
  ask turtles [ ask other turtles-here [ask link-with myself [ set meets meets + .5]]]

end
```